# ZenCart file upload issue

Tags: file-upload, zen-cart

I am facing an issue while file uploading.
Got below in error log:

```
#1  is_uploaded_file() called at [/home/public_html/includes/classes/upload.php:86]
#2  upload->parse() called at [/home/public_html/manage/includes/modules/new_product_preview.php:148]
#3  require(/home/public_html/manage/includes/modules/new_product_preview.php) called at [/home/public_html/manage/product.php:120]
```

Limits that are set for file upload:

```
* file_uploads: On
* upload_max_filesize: 200M
* max_input_time: 60
* memory_limit: 1024M
* max_execution_time : 100000
* post_max_size: 200M
```

File up to 2MB uploaded successfully, larger size files not uploaded

Answer (score 0):

Please see the documentation on file uploads: https://www.zen-cart.com/content.php?306-what-is-the-maximum-file-upload-size-for-my-site

Make sure:

- The setting in the admin is also higher then 2MB
- The php settings are properly loaded by calling phpinfo() from within your project.

Note: Your 'error' misses an actual error message, it's just a notice